# Divide certain distinct row values into separate columns

Tags: c#, performance, sql, linq, .net-datatable

This might be difficult for me to describe clearly but I will try anyway. Also note that this is entirely speculative; it might not even be able to run any faster (that is why I am asking).

This is a question directed at performance. I have been trying to improve the performance of a method and have managed to improve it quite a bit already (around 40% faster). Right now, the entire process takes about 1 minute and 15 seconds to complete. I would like to see if maybe you guys can see some obvious faults in my code and how we could perhaps improve it even further, seeing as I am not quite satisfied yet.

The method fetches a big amount of data from a couple of databases and needs to be displayed in a grid in a certain way. Here is the heavy part of the method. I will describe it in more detail after:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(sqlConnectionString);

//Find minimum value of N in the specified timespan
var headerMin = ((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                  where Convert.ToDateTime(y.StartTime) >= GlobalVariables.StartTimeMSA
                  select y.N).Min());

//Find maximum value of N in the specified timespan
var headerMax = ((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                  where Convert.ToDateTime(y.StartTime) <= GlobalVariables.EndTimeMSA
                  select y.N).Max());

//Find appropriate data in the specified timespan (min and max headerid)
var msaData = from x in dbContext.Testdatas
              where x.HeaderID >= headerMin
                                    &&
                    x.HeaderID <= headerMax

              select new
              {
                  StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime((from z in dbContext.Testheaders
                                                 where x.HeaderID == z.N
                                                 select z.StartTime).FirstOrDefault()),

                  DUT_id = Convert.ToString((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                                             where x.HeaderID == y.N
                                             select y.DUT_id).FirstOrDefault()),

                  Meas = (double)x.Meas,

                  x.Step,

                  x.LogID,

                  x.HeaderID,

                  printID = Convert.ToInt32((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                                             where x.HeaderID == y.N
                                             select y.PrintID).FirstOrDefault()),

                  Prod_Blok = Convert.ToInt32((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                                               where x.HeaderID == y.N
                                               select y.Prod_Blok).FirstOrDefault()),


                  Rep_Count = Convert.ToInt32((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                                               where x.HeaderID == y.N
                                               select y.Rep_Count).FirstOrDefault()),

                  Operator = Convert.ToString((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                                               where x.HeaderID == y.N
                                               select y.Operator).FirstOrDefault()),
              };

msaDataTable.Columns.Add("Time");
msaDataTable.Columns.Add("DUT");
msaDataTable.Columns.Add("Position");

var functionDistinct = msaData.Select(x => new { x.Step, x.LogID }).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Step).ThenBy(x => x.LogID);

//Add columns to datatable corresponding to each function. The number of columns is only known at runtime.
foreach (var item in functionDistinct)
{
    var column = new DataColumn() { DataType = typeof(double), ColumnName = String.Format("{0}-{1}", item.Step, item.LogID), AllowDBNull = true };

    msaDataTable.Columns.Add(column);
}

var distinctHeaderID = msaData.Select(x => x.HeaderID).Distinct();

foreach (var headerID in distinctHeaderID)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    //Fetch the data for the current headerID
    var headerIDData = msaData.Where(x => x.HeaderID == headerID).Select(x => new { x.StartTime, x.DUT_id, x.printID, x.Step, x.LogID, x.Meas }).ToList();

    if (headerIDData != null)
    {
        DataRow row = msaDataTable.NewRow();

        row["Time"] = headerIDData.FirstOrDefault().StartTime;
        row["DUT"] = headerIDData.FirstOrDefault().DUT_id;
        row["Position"] = headerIDData.FirstOrDefault().printID;

        //Run through the data for the current headerID and assign the values to the right function.
        foreach (var data in headerIDData)
        {
            string function = String.Format("{0}-{1}", data.Step, data.LogID);
            row[function] = data.Meas;
        }

        msaDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Some sample rows from the database query (msaData) could look like this (these are just made up):

[image: Sample rows]

I am basically taking those sample rows and combine them into a single row, where the distinct Step and LogID are combined into "functions" shown as columns with the Measurements as cell values. To illustrate, here is how the above picture would be displayed correctly:

[image: Sample rows correct]

A few notes:

- Step and LogID combined are known as a "function". In the database they are separated into two columns instead of just the function. For example, Step could have a field value of 5 and LogID 1. Then the function would be known as 5-1. This is what I am displaying as columns instead.
- To achieve the goal I am creating a DataTable and binding it to the grid after I am done filling it with appropriate data.
- I need to create the columns dynamically as there is no way to know how many functions there are at design time. That is the reason I am using a DataTable in the first place instead of just creating a class and an `ObservableCollection` for example.
- The above sample rows is a very small amount of what the actual data will consist of. We are talking 400000 rows in the test scenario I am running currently.

Are there any immediate problems in my code you can spot? Perhaps some places where a `ToList()` call could improve performance (even though I have tried some already). Or perhaps another way to tackle how I combine the rows?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you return 400k rows to an end user? That's sure to cause the user's brain to overflow with too much data.

Comment: Well the thing is that the number of rows will be reduced greatly before it is shown to the user, since the number of functions can be as big as about 70. This is a client request to get it shown this way and with my method it is shown the way they want it. I am using DevExpress so it will be easy for them to search for items in the grid. But the most common use will be to export the grid data into excel, where they will use some statistical program (that I have no idea how works or what actually is) to do some automatic modifications/readings on the data.

Comment: Furthermore, it might be acceptable for them for the application to take this long before spewing out the data, but I find it somewhat slow. I am asking the question out of curiosity to see if anyone can spot some obvious flaws, seeing as I am relatively new to C# and haven't actually done an application like this before. Hence why I stated the question as merely speculative :)

Comment: Have you looked at the generated SQL and looked at the plan and stats for it?

Comment: @RobH I am not sure what you mean. I have checked it is the right data coming out and the count, but I do not actually know what the plan and stats are. Are they used for optimization? Perhaps I should just Google that actually.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah have a google around analysing query plans in SQL Server. You will be able to speed your function up more effectively by speeding up the SQL aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking that the 2 calls at the beginning might be reduced to one.  Which should cut down the time somewhat.  Something like this:

```
var headers = ((from y in dbContext.Testheaders
                  let startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(y.StartTime)
                  where startTime >= GlobalVariables.StartTimeMSA &&
                        startTime <= GlobalVariables.EndTimeMSA
                  select y.N));

//Find minimum value of N in the specified timespan
var headerMin = headers.Min();
//Find maximum value of N in the specified timespan
var headerMax = headers.Max());
```

In a similar vein extracting the appropriate header, only once for each record your looking at in testDatas should eliminate the queries your doing in the new block.  Something like this:

```
var msaData = from x in dbContext.Testdatas
                where x.HeaderID >= headerMin
                                    &&
                    x.HeaderID <= headerMax
                let header = (from h in dbContext.Testheaders
                            where x.HeaderID == h.N
                            select h).FirstOrDefault()  
                select new
                {
                    StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(header.StartTime),

                    DUT_id = Convert.ToString(header.DUT_id),

                    Meas = (double)x.Meas,

                    x.Step,

                    x.LogID,

                    x.HeaderID,

                    printID = Convert.ToInt32(header.PrintID),

                    Prod_Blok = Convert.ToInt32(header.Prod_Blok),


                    Rep_Count = Convert.ToInt32(header.Rep_Count),

                    Operator = Convert.ToString(header.Operator),
                };
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, haven't heard of the let clause before. I'll try this out.

Comment: Doing this actually did cut the elapsed time a bit. Now it is down to about 50 seconds which I do find somewhat acceptable. Thanks! I'll go read what let actually does to gain a bit of understanding of what you did.

Answer (score 0):

- You should call `ToList()` at the big `Select()` and remove the calls to `ToList()` here

  > ```
  > var functionDistinct = msaData.Select(x => new { x.Step, x.LogID
  >        }).Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Step).ThenBy(x => x.LogID);
  > ```

  or here

  > ```
  > var headerIDData = msaData.Where(x => x.HeaderID == headerID).Select(x => new {   
  >       x.StartTime, x.DUT_id, x.printID, x.Step, x.LogID, x.Meas }).ToList();
  > ```
- Skip the creation of the anonymous types where you don't need it.
- Replace the check `headerIDData != null` with `headerIDData.Any()`, because it can't be `null`
- call `Distinct()` before `Select()` by implementing an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

  > ```
  > var distinctHeaderID = msaData.Select(x => x.HeaderID).Distinct();
  > ```

Comment: Alright, tried removing the ToList() calls where you specified. Here are the elapsed times:

`Time elapsed: 00:01:06.7339292 (with the ToList() calls)`
`Time elapsed: 00:03:20.5137437 (removing the ToList() calls)`

So removing the ToList() calls basically triples the elapsed time.

Comment: Oh yeah, let me update the question with that query.

Comment: Once again, the elapsed time was way longer with calling the ToList() at the initial msaData and removing it from `functionDistinct` and `headerIDData`. Performance: `Time elapsed: 00:05:41.6543591`. Performance with old code: `Time elapsed: 00:00:58.3041223`.

Comment: So, the call to `ToList()` will take almost 5 minutes ?

Comment: Apparently, yes. Does seem a bit weird.